# SQL - counting all the file extensions

Tags: mysql, sql

I hope someone can help me out.
I have a table where I get a file id and file name. My goal is to get the amount of each file extension.

This is an example of the table:

```
FILEID           FILENAME
  1              file1.pdf
  2              file2.png
  3              file3.jpg
  4              file4.pdf
  5              file5.png
```

and I'm trying to get something like this

```
Extension        Count
.pdf              2
.png              2
.jpg              1
```

I'm able to get all the information after the '.' using the following query but I can't seem to be able to get the count

```
select SUBSTRING(filename,charindex('.',filename,1),5)
from FILES
```

Thank you

Comment: Why can't you get the count? Don't you know how to use the `COUNT()` function with `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Since when MySQL has `CHARINDEX()`?

Comment: It seems you're using `MSSQL` but not `MySQL`, aren't you ..?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan yes, isn't all the same language? Sorry I'm kind of new databases.

Comment: SQL has lots of standard rules but some functions and rules may differ from a DB brand to the other one. i.e. might be product spesific. I think your DB is MS-SQL(or sql-server), and you may convert your tag to `sql-server`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(filename, '.', -1) as suffix, count(*)
from files
group by suffix;
```

This does not include the `'.'`.  If you want that, bring it back in:

```
select concat('.', substring_index(filename, '.', -1)) as suffix, count(*)
from files
group by suffix;
```

Comment: I'm getting the message: 'substring_index' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @sergio089 . ..  `substring_index()` is and has been a part of MySQL since, perhaps, time immemorial (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index).  If you are not using MySQL, I would suggest that you ask another question, with the appropriate database tag.

Answer (score 1):

you might use `substring()` with `instr()` function :

```
select substring(filename,instr(filename,'.'),length(filename)) as extension,
       count(1) as count
  from files
 group by extension
```

[***Rextester Demo for MySQL case***](http://rextester.com/EWGKJA48210)

**Edit** : I realised that you're using MS-SQL, so you may use :

```
select substring(filename,charindex('.',filename,1),5) as extension,
       count(1) as count
  from files
 group by substring(filename,charindex('.',filename,1),5);
```

[***Rextester Demo for MS-SQL case***](http://rextester.com/DJPA29147)

Comment: I'm getting the message :'instr' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @sergio089 what's your DB version? ( It starts from version MySQL 3.23 )